# How can I serialize Django REST framework Serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jsonschema, serialization

Maybe this isn't possible but given a Django Serializer class like this:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(min_length=1, max_length=200)
```

I'd like there to be a way for the client to get it like a JSON Schema like this (I don't particularly care about the format, OpenAPI would be okay too):

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/example.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "ExampleSerializer",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 200
    }
  }
}
```

The advantage of this is that I don't have to duplicate the schema logic in the client too. I tried to use their [CoreAPI](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/coreapi/schemas/) which documents endpoints but it seems like in order to use it I'd need to convert all my serializers to use their `AutoSchema` format. I don't want to do because I already have it in the seralizer format. What's the recommended way to do this? If there isn't one ([already asked on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/7lkl2i/what_do_people_use_to_create_forms_from_backend/)), it'd be relatively easy for me to create a Serializer-to-JSONSchema converter but I can't imagine I'm the first person to have wanted this.

Comment: A quick read in the DRF documentation lead me to the OpenAPI schema generation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#generating-an-openapi-schema . It has been a while since I last played around with DRF so I can not provide much assistance.

Comment: Thanks Kendas, but that has the limitation that I need to re-write my serializers in a new format -- I just want to write it once.

Comment: appears to not exist in current maintained state anywhere